# Is there a way to change browser in puppeteer?

Tags: browser, puppeteer

I want to change browser in one run.
Is there any way to do this?

For example, 
At first, launch chrome browser.
When variable became multiple of 2, change browser to edge, 
When variable became multiple of 3, change browser to firefox.

I tried this.

```
(async () => {
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        executablePath: "chrome path",
    });
    var page = await browser.newPage();

    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
　　
        // change browser to edge 
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            await browser.close();
            browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                executablePath: "edge path",
            page = await browser.newPage();
            });
　　 
        // change browser to firefox
        }else if (i % 3 == 0) {
            await browser.close();
            browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                product: 'firefox',
            });
            page = await browser.newPage();
        }
    }
})();
```

Error Message

```
 Protocol error (Page.navigate): Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer-core');
```

and then change **executablePath:**

[image]

Comment: You can also switch from chrome to firefox by setting product: option inside config.

Comment: inside which config can you be more clear?